# How would I delete a playlist using YouTube API V3? Or would I have to use an AJAX DELETE method?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

a lot of people complain they have too many YouTube playlists and it sucks to delete them one at a time. Using the YouTube V3 API, would it be possible for me to programmatically delete their playlists for them? If not, could I do a DELETE call to YouTube using Angular client side or node.js serverside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need to do is call `playlists.list()` to retrieve the ids for all of the playlists you would like to delete, and then delete them using `playlists.delete()`. You can see the details for these methods here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists